# Bootstrap datepicker update method causing issues

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to use the [bootstrap datepicker from eternicode](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), which is a fork of the original eyecon picker.

I've added a [jsfiddle example of what I'm trying to do](http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/yqestkdf/14/).

At the bottom of all the js in the fiddle is where I initialize my datepicker. 
I added a `setTimout` so I could simulate changing the datepickers date dynamically. 
I have read where you need to call `datepicker('update');` after you do a `setDate` so it updates the pickers UI.

When I do this it's causing some issues. If you click on the input field to show the calendar, the calendar will display showing the highlighted date as today's date not the new date I updated it with.

When you close the picker it will append todays date to the end of the input value. 
This is not normal behavior. All I'm trying to do is set a new date and have it update the UI picker at the same time.

HTML

```
<div class="input-append date" id="date-picker">
    <input class="span6" size="16" type="text">
    <span class="add-on"><i class=""></i></span>
</div>
```

```js
var picker = $('#date-picker').datepicker({format:'M d, yyyy' });

var d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);

setTimeout(function(){
  picker.datepicker("setDate", d).datepicker('update');
},3000);
```

Comment: ericB, You should update your example to use this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/yqestkdf/16/) which cleans up the external code by moving it to external resources instead of keeping it inline.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems that you can only pass the date in the following format in order to keep the datepicker display the date properly:

```
picker.datepicker('update', new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()));
```

Where `d` is your desired date.

Comment: +1, that looks like it resolves it.  here's a [simplified fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/yqestkdf/15/) with this answer and the resources linked externally

Comment: Thanks Miron but I tried that in my jsfiddle like I provided above and it still doesn't update the UI correctly.  picker.datepicker('update', new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDate()+1));

Comment: Ah I spoke too soon. So I needed to also take out the setDate and just use the update instead. picker.datepicker('update', date);

Comment: Sure, without `datepicker("setDate", d)` it works ;)

Comment: Wow that was a good days work wasted. Thank you so much for letting me know it only allows year, month and date. I really think the docs should have that included for the update method. Thank you Thank you.

Comment: Miron I notice that if you hit any key when you have the picker open and then when it closes it appends the new date to the other one. Looks like its firing some event again ? Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/chapster11/yqestkdf/17/

Answer (score -2):

close your `<input class="span6" size="16" type="text"   /   >` <del>it seems to work then</del>

maybe look at that the class `input-append` does